# jquery populate new data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a sample program using JQuery

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/0f4kz0hk/)

I'm having a trouble in adding new table row using data attribute, that should be displayed before the button or with the table row.

**JS:**

```
var newhtml = '<table><tr><td>data1</td><td>data2</td><td>data3</td></tr><!--show here--><!--new table row added in clicking more--><tr><td></td><td></td><td><button>more</button></td></tr></table>';

$(".advanced-info").click(function(){
        console.log($("#" + $(this).attr("data-div")).html().length);
       if ($("#" + $(this).attr("data-div")).html().length > 0) {

         $("#" + $(this).attr("data-div")).empty();
       } else {
       $("#" + $(this).attr("data-div")).append(newhtml);
       }
    });
```

output

[image]

[image]

I apologize my problem is not clear

Comment: Did you try just adding jQuery to that -> https://jsfiddle.net/0f4kz0hk/1/

Comment: I try to use a copy of the script and made some changes in the class but it didn't work

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/0f4kz0hk/2/

Comment: Please explain your issue clearly.

Comment: I update my post sir

Comment: @misdirection Is that solved?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

I've changed the usage of .attr to .data.

```js
var newhtml = '<table><tr><td>data1</td><td>data2</td><td>data3</td></tr><tr><td></td><td></td><td><button>more</button></td></tr></table>';

$(".advanced-info").click(function() {
  console.log($("#" + $(this).attr("data-div")).html().length);
  if ($("#" + $(this).data("div")).html().length > 0) {
    $("#" + $(this).data("div")).empty();
  } else {
    $("#" + $(this).data("div")).append(newhtml);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href='#' class='advanced-info' data-div='adv1'>Advanced Options</a>
<div id='adv1'></div>
<br/>
<br/>

<a href='#' class='advanced-info' data-div='adv2'>Advanced Options</a>
<div id='adv2'>
</div>
<br/>
<br/>



<a href='#' class='advanced-info' data-div='adv3'>Advanced Options</a>
<div id='adv3'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way.

```js
var newhtml = '<table><tr style="display:none;"><td>data1</td><td>data2</td><td>data3</td></tr><tr><td></td><td></td><td><button>more</button></td></tr></table>';

$(".advanced-info").click(function() {
  console.log($("#" + $(this).attr("data-div")).html().length);
  if ($("#" + $(this).attr("data-div")).html().length > 0) {

    $("#" + $(this).attr("data-div")).empty();
  } else {
    $("#" + $(this).attr("data-div")).append(newhtml);
  }
});

$("div").on("click", "button", function() {
  $(this).closest("table").find("tr:eq(0)").css("display", "table-row");
  $(this).hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href='#' class='advanced-info' data-div='adv1'>Advanced Options</a>
<div id='adv1'></div>
<br/>
<br/>

<a href='#' class='advanced-info' data-div='adv2'>Advanced Options</a>
<div id='adv2'></div>
<br/>
<br/>

<a href='#' class='advanced-info' data-div='adv3'>Advanced Options</a>
<div id='adv3'></div>
```

Hope this your need!